# Magento 1.x Product Attribute Sets Not Showing on product edit page

Tags: magento-1.9

On the product edit page in the admin, only the system attribute groups are showing (Inventory, Categories, Related Products, etc), and none of the group tabs from the products attribute set are showing (General, etc)  Also the website selector above is not showing either.  I have tried re-indexing, and have checked the database, and the product is assigned to the correct attribute set and that set has groups in it with attributes assigned to them.  Also, I can create new attributes, which show up in the database, but not in the attribute admin, or as unassigned attributes in the attribute set editor.

[image]

Comment: have you checked system.log and exception.log?

Comment: There's nothing in either.

Comment: No PHP errors either.  The only thing I did was try and add a new custom product attribute through the admin interface.  Then the default attribute set groups disappeared.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the attribute not pulling in the data from the catalog_eav_attribute table for the attribute.  Can't figure out why though as the records are there, and the keys match.

Answer (score 1):

Any attribute you are adding, must be assigned to some attribute set. Then will it will be appeared in the product entry form if you choose the right attribute while adding products.

Comment: No the problem is existing attributes disappeared.  I tracked it down to them coming back as not visible, however the is_visible field in the database is set to 1 for these attributes, so I'm not sure what's going on with it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  In the eav_entity_type table, the catalog_product type record was missing values for:

additional_attribute_table (value: 'catalog/eav_attribute')
entity_attribute_collection (value: 'catalog/product_attribute_collection')